# Create A function Which can do specific Sum on entire table

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongo DB dataset Like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8a75cdec129c86c6a2aaca"),
    "asset" : "121",
    "A" : 6,
    "C" : 12,
    "B" : 4,
    "D" : 8,
    "finalAB" : "",
    "finalCD" : "",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8a75cdec129c86c6a2aaca"),
    "asset" : "122",
    "A" : 8,
    "C" : 14,
    "B" : 6,
    "D" : 10,
    "finalAB" : "",
    "finalCD" : "",
}......upto 4k Entry Like this
```

Now I want to Create MongoDB function Which can do the Entire Table Calculation of "finalAB" & "finalCD"

> NOTE: finalAB = A + B and finalCD = C + D.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `update` here because you're referring to other fields in your update however you can try to use Aggregation Framework:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            finalAB: { $add: [ "$A", "$B" ] },
            finalCD: { $add: [ "$C", "$D" ] },
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "col"
    }
])
```

[$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) simply replaces your `finalAB` and `finalCD` with new values. [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) is a way to redirect aggregation ouput to a new collection. That's how you can replace (update) existing collection.

Comment: Thanks, Buddy. Your suggested approach is really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Use Aggregate Query :

```
       app.get("/getTotal",function(req,res){   

             YourModel.aggregate([
               {   
                    $addFields: {
                       finalAB: { $add: [ "$A", "$B" ] },
                       finalCD: { $add: [ "$C", "$D" ] },
                    }
              },
              { 
                 $group:{ _id:null,
                          finalAB:{ $sum: "$finalAB"},
                          finalCD:{ $sum: "$finalCD"}
                        }
              }
             ],function(err,result){
                     res.json(result);   
              });

         });
```

Use full Link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: Really appreciates for giving the alternate solution.